# Why this random variable is constant a.e.?

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables

**Problem:**

Suppose $(X_n)_{n \geq 1}$ are indipendent random variables defined in $(\Omega, \mathscr{A},\mathbb{P})$.
Define $Y=\limsup _{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{1 \leq p \leq n}X_p$ and $Z=\liminf _{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{1 \leq p \leq n}X_p$. How can I prove that $Y$ and $Z$ are costant almost everywhere?

**My attempt:**

I know it is related with Kolmogorov's zero-one law. I can solve the simplier case $\limsup_n X_n$ but I cannot solve the problem above.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Show that $Y$ and $Z$ are $\mathcal{T}:= \bigcap_{k=1}^\infty  \sigma(X_k, X_{k+1, \dots})$-measurable. Hence, Kolmogorov's $0$-$1$ law applies (due to independence) and we can conclude that
$$\Bbb{P}(Y \in A) \in \{0,1\}$$
for all Borel sets $A$. Similarly for $Z$. Subsequently, use/prove the following lemma:

**Lemma**: If a random variable satisfies $\Bbb{P}(Y \in A) \in \{0,1\}$ for all Borel sets $A$, then $Y$ is constant almost surely.

Answer (score 0):

For any $k$ $\frac  1n \sum\limits_{p=1}^{k}X_p \to 0$. So we can take the sum from $k+1$ to $\infty$. This shows that $Y$ and $Z$ are measurable w.r.t. $\sigma (X_{k+1},X_{k+2},...)$ for each $k$. Apply $0-1$ law now.